# Mask a domain name on a browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

I know this can be done but I have only a few minutes to figure out how before Christmas overtakes the need.
I have a domain that hosts services for several clients that run in Subfolders of the main domain.
I have one client who wants THEIR name to show up in the addressbar of the browser.

This is a normal Apache Website on a Windows Hosting Server.

The client purchased a special domain name that they want me to use but I do not know how to simply change the dhcp to point to my Servers IP and not show up as My Server's normal domain name rather than the name they want me to use.

It is possible that it is something very easy.  Someone mentioned using masking but I need to have a specific method that will work without interfering with the other domain normally used.

Their only complaint/concern is what shows in the browser addressbar.  I might be worrying for nothing and maybe all that is required is to put their website along wise my own and point the dns to my servers ip.  But I have zero time to experiment and must hit a homerun on the first try.

Maybe Htaccess?  I just need to know a for certain method.  I only get one chance to do it

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The is an Apache level configuration that you need to make.  You need to have their DNS resolve to the ip address of your server.  than you need either name-based or IP-based virtual hosts configured in Apache.

Comment: Thanks  that is sort of what I thought and I have already changed the DNS to point to my server.  I have also created the "site" in the WAMP manager  I do see a place to configure the virtual host and I have not done that yet so that is my next thing to do.